# Selenium Project : Errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

```java
package edurekha;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 


import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class Firstscript {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty(" webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\java n other software executables\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-username']")).sendKeys("xyz@yahoo.com");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-signin']")).click();

    }

}
```

getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at edurekha.Firstscript.main(Firstscript.java:17)
```

Comment: Do you have this in the imports?  import org.openqa.selenium.By;

Comment: try to handle the exceptions internally, don't throws them because after the main no other can catch them (tip)

Answer (score 1):

1) You are importing wrong package: 
   Just replace import openqa.selenium.By; with import org.openqa.selenium.By;

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `import openqa.selenium.By;`
with
`import org.openqa.selenium.By;`